# java ", imcompatable types issue im having with my code: char cannot be converted to a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

For this java program I am taking in a string then printing/saving the string of characters in order of their frequency.

```
import java.util.*;

public class freqChar
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        int myArray[] = new int[256];
        int len = s.length();
        String array1 [] = new String [len];

        String strArray [] = new String [len];

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            myArray[(int)s.charAt(i)]++;
        }

        for(int i = s.length(); i > 0; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)
            {
                if(myArray[j] == i)   // Here I am trying to fill a  string array with the characters from the original string after I have casted them back from ints.
                {
                    int g = 0;
                    char x = ((char)(j));
                    array1[g] = x;
                    g++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(array1[i] + " ");
        }
   }
}
```

When I compile it gives me the error:

> cannot convert char to a string.

Comment: Please include the line number in the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: a `char` is not a `String` so putting a `char` into an array of `String`s won't work.

But its very easy to fix the problem, just replace `char x =((char)(j));` with `char x = Character.toString((char) j);`

Comment: Thanks MartinS, My tired brain has it that a char can also be a string as in "a" is a char and "a" can also be a string. Your a star.